# “! Misplaced \omit” error in multicolumn and BlackCell

Tags: tables, backgrounds, multicolumn

I ran into a problem with “! Misplaced \omit” error. I have searched quite hard to find the relevant problem but only find mine is similar with [bigbadpiano's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85861/multicolumn-misplaced-omit-problem) in which A.Ellett generated a nice table with WME.

However, my personal desire is to put one multicolumn as black background and white text, for instance: [image: an failed example]

This is an failed example since the whole first row should be black. I also get an error in Log File:"
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.10 ...multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\BlackCell{Dataset A}}
                                                   \\hline
I expect to see \omit only after tab marks or the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case."

If this question is duplicate, I am really sorry but I couldn't find the correct answer to my specific problem. In this case, please inform me the exact answer and I will delete this question later. Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\BlackCell[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{black}\textcolor{white}{#1}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
     \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\BlackCell{Dataset A}} \\\hline
 L (m)  & T (s) & T$^2$ (s$^2$) & L$^{1/2}$ (m$^{1/2}$) & $\Delta$T$^2$ (s$^2$) & $\Delta$T (s) & Fitted T$^2$ (s$^2$) & Fitted T (s) \\ \hline
    0.2 & 0.626 & 0.392         & 0.447                 & 0.006                 & 0.005         & 0.394                & 0.662 \\ 
    0.3 & 0.889 & 0.790         & 0.548                 & 0.009                 & 0.005         & 0.797                & 0.889 \\ 
    0.4 & 1.105 & 1.221         & 0.632                 & 0.011                 & 0.005         & 1.201                & 1.081 \\ 
    0.5 & 1.261 & 1.590         & 0.707                 & 0.013                 & 0.005         & 1.604                & 1.250 \\ 
    0.6 & 1.420 & 2.016         & 0.775                 & 0.014                 & 0.005         & 2.008                & 1.403 \\ 
    0.7 & 1.555 & 2.418         & 0.837                 & 0.016                 & 0.005         & 2.411                & 1.543 \\ 
    0.8 & 1.679 & 2.819         & 0.894                 & 0.017                 & 0.005         & 2.814                & 1.674 \\ 
    0.9 & 1.798 & 3.233         & 0.949                 & 0.018                 & 0.005         & 3.218                & 1.797 \\ 
    1.0 & 1.901 & 3.614         & 1.000                 & 0.019                 & 0.005         & 3.621                & 1.913 \\ 
    1.1 & 2.000 & 4.000         & 1.049                 & 0.020                 & 0.005         & 4.025                & 2.023 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `\multicolumn` inside a `\multicolumn` which is not allowed (and you had a missing `%` at end of line). Use

```
\newcommand\BlackCell[1]{%
  \cellcolor{black}\textcolor{white}{#1}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It works perfectly now! I don't know what the purposes of the two %s. Are they used to define the invoked functions, while {} are the body of this command?

Comment: @Frank No they are comment markers to avoid making spurious space: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/1090